# Python input for Spectral Clustering

Tags: python, io

I am using the code from https://github.com/pin3da/spectral-clustering/blob/master/spectral/utils.py to spectrally cluster data in https://cs.joensuu.fi/sipu/datasets/s1.txt

May i know how I can change the code such that it can take in txt file as input?
I have given the original code below for reference

**Original code from GitHub**

```
 import numpy
 import scipy.io
 import h5py


def load_dot_mat(path, db_name):
     try:
        mat = scipy.io.loadmat(path)
     except NotImplementedError:
          mat = h5py.File(path)

    return numpy.array(mat[db_name]).transpose()
```

I do not understand the purpose of the variable, *db_name*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show here just opens a given `mat` or `h5` file. The path to the file (`path`) and the name of the data set within the file (`db_name`) are provided as arguments to the `load_dot_mat` function.

To load your txt file, we can create our own little load function:

```
def load_txt(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        data = [[int(x) for x in line.split(" ") if x != ""] for line in f]
    return np.array(data)
```

This function takes the path to your "txt" file as an argument an returns a numpy array with the data from your file. The data array has shape (5000,2) for the file you provided. You may want to use `float` instead of `int`, if other files contain float values and not only integers.

The complete clustering step for your data could then look like this:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn
from spectral import  affinity, clustering

seaborn.set()


def load_txt(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        data = [[int(x) for x in line.split(" ") if x != ""] for line in f]
    return np.array(data)


data = load_txt("s1.txt")

A = affinity.com_aff_local_scaling(data)
n_cls = 15  # found by looking at your data
Y = clustering.spectral_clustering(A, n_cls)
colors = np.array(list(islice(cycle(seaborn.color_palette()), int(max(Y) + 1))))
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(data[:, 0], data[:, 1], color=colors[Y], s=6, alpha=0.6)
plt.show()
```

[image]